# Allow BBPress participant role to trash topics

Tags: php, functions, bbpress, user-roles

I have a small project with BBPress roles, here is what needs to happen if at all possible.

**Participant Role**

- Participants should be able to trash posts.
- Participants should be able to restore trashed posts.
- Participants should only be able to restore or trash posts based on the BBPress edit time set in the forum options.
- This should only be applied to the posts Participants create. They should not be able to edit, trash, or restore anyone else s topic or reply.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the similar scenario, I had used [Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/plugin) to customize capabilities. It will allow you to change capabilities of any role without diving into codes. Please take a look.

Comment: I found an alternate solution, thanks for helping anyway.